# How do I resolve import conflicts in scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

I launched this shell from sbt with the "console-project" command.

```
scala> settings
<console>:24: error: reference to settings is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import Keys._
and import settings
       settings
       ^
```

How do I get the shell to display the settings object, not Keys.settings?

Comment: Shot in the dark, as I don't have SBT nor Keys nor settings... Try `import Keys.{ settings => keys_settings }` I don't know if it works in the REPL

Comment: That doesn't help.  The problem is that I'm not doing the importing myself, sbt is doing it for me before I gain access to the shell prompt.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the package layout ? What object is in what package ?

Comment: Keys is sbt.Keys.  See: 
https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.10/main/Keys.scala

Comment: Can you specify from which package you want the `settings` object?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that you imported `Keys._` and `settings` yourself you can rename `settings` from `Keys`, like so:

```
import Keys.{settings => keySettings, _}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always resolve conflicts by using the full path to the object you want.
So if you want `settings` defined in package/object `repl` than you can refer to `repl.settings`.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't need the other settings, you can just ignore it by renaming it to :

```
import Keys.{settings => _, _}
```

Comment: Downvoting for poor grammar and script-kiddie spelling

Comment: That doesn't work.

    > console-project
    [info] Starting scala interpreter...
    [info] 
    import sbt._
    import Process._
    import Keys._
    import currentState._
    import extracted._
    Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1 <snip>.
    scala> import Keys.{settings => _, _}
    import Keys.{settings=>_, _}
    
    scala> settings                      
    <console>:27: error: reference to settings is ambiguous;
    it is imported twice in the same scope by
    import Keys._
    and import settings
           settings
           ^

Answer (score 0):

You should add this libs to you class-path: (this is for play-framewrk 2.0 application, But I hope it could help)

```
/home/user/play/framework/sbt/boot/scala-2.9.1/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt/0.11.0
```

there is a jar with name main_2.9.1-0.11.0.jar where you can find the **Keys**. In fact it is enough to export this jar only to your class-path.